# jquery not properly serializing json in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let me start by saying I am not extremely familiar with Javascript and I cannot figure out what is going on here.

I have the following function:

```
        self.search = function () {

            var searchTerms = {
                "City":  this.cityName,
                "State": this.stateName,
                "StoreNumber": this.storeNumber,
                };                


                $.ajax("/api/SearchApi", {
                    data: searchTerms,
                    type: "POST", contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result);                            
                        }
                    }
                });
```

When I submit, what happens is that instead of submitting a nice JSON object as expected, it submits a JSON objected formatted as so: `"City=testing&State=AL&StoreNumber=test "`

Ideally I would like to use a GET method that passes the object to my server so that I can return the results, but when I use a get method, it simply appends the above to the API call url resulting in a URL request formed as so: `http://localhost:57175/api/SearchApi?City=testing&State=AL&StoreNumber=test`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you add the dataType of JSON to your `$.ajax({ });` object. That should solve the problem!

```
$.ajax({ 
    // ...

    data     : JSON.stringify( searchTerms ), // Encode it properly like so
    dataType : "json", 

    // ...
});
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify( searchTerms ), // just for good measure` is actually required if he wants the server to receive the data as JSON. +1

Comment: Thank you.  I removed contentType: "application/json" and replaced it with the dataType and it worked very nicely.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: @RaySülzer `contentType` is for the **returning** `data` that you'll be getting back (if any) from success, almost had it!

Comment: @KevinB Haha well I'm glad I randomly do it then! For some reason, I thought that jQuery tries to do this for you based on the `dataType` you put in.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS contentType is for the data jQuery is **sending** to php, so `contentType: "application/json"` should always be paired with `data: JSON.stringify( thedata )`. `dataType` is for what php is returning to jquery. We may be saying the same thing just differently.

Comment: @KevinB Reading the docs now, guess I had them strangely mixed up... a little exhausted this morning. thanks kev

Comment: from the jQuery documentation :
 "contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')
Type: String
When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax(), then it'll always be sent to the server (even if no data is sent). If no charset is specified, data will be transmitted to the server using the server's default charset; you must decode this appropriately on the server side." http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

2 Things

1. Add the json content type(not the data type) to your ajax object important to note is the charset your server is using in this case utf-8.
2. Use the Json2 Library to stringify and parse Json when sending and retrieving it can be found here : https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url: URL,
       type: "POST",
       //Stringify the data you send to make shure its properly encoded
       data: JSON.stringify(DATA),  
       //This is the type  for the data that  gets sent            
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       //This is for the data you receive
       dataType: "json"
   }).done(function(data) {
      var dataYouGet = JSON.parse(data);
   }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

   }).always(function(data) {

   });
   ```